# What is withRouter for in react-router-dom?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I've [sometimes seen](https://github.com/lore/www.lorejs.org/blob/41f9b34a67cb676984daf0cda4126a6bf4e14fcd/src/pages/cli/lore-generate-component/options/router.js) people wrap their components in `withRouter` when they are exporting them:

```js
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

class Foo extends React.Component {
  // ...
}

export default withRouter(Foo);
```

What is this for, and when should I use it?

Answer (score 307, accepted):

When you include a main page component in your app, it is often wrapped in a `<Route>` component like this:

```
<Route path="/movies" component={MoviesIndex} />
```

By doing this, the `MoviesIndex` component has access to `this.props.history` so it can redirect the user with `this.props.history.push`.

Some components (commonly a header component) appear on every page, so are not wrapped in a `<Route>`:

```
render() {
  return (<Header />);
}
```

This means the header cannot redirect the user.

To get around this problem, the header component can be wrapped in a [`withRouter`](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/withRouter.md) function, either when it is exported:

```
export default withRouter(Header)
```

This gives the `Header` component access to `this.props.history`, which means the header can now redirect the user.

Comment: As stated in [@msoliman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56622289/2554605), `withRouter` also gives access to `match` and `location`. It would be nice if the accepted answer mentioned that, since redirecting the user is not the only use case for `withRouter`. This is a nice self-qna otherwise.

Comment: Also, if you need the <Link> and <NavLink> from router, it is required to use the withRouter HOC.

Comment: I think the answer would be more complete if mentioned why `history` or `match` are not present by default? i.e. Why `withRouter` should be mentioned explicitly?

Comment: what if we wrap App component by BrowserRouter  in index.js, then we will not require withRouter at all, please suggest?

Answer (score 69):

`withRouter` is a higher order component that will pass closest route's `match`, current `location`, and `history` props to the wrapped component whenever it renders. simply it connects component to the router.

Not all components, especially the shared components, will have the access to such router's props. Inside its wrapped components, you would be able to access `location` prop and get more information like `location.pathname` or redirect the user to different url using `this.props.history.push`.

Here's a complete example from their github page:

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { withRouter } from "react-router";

// A simple component that shows the pathname of the current location
class ShowTheLocation extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    match: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    location: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    history: PropTypes.object.isRequired
  };

  render() {
    const { match, location, history } = this.props;

    return <div>You are now at {location.pathname}</div>;
  }
}

// Create a new component that is "connected" (to borrow redux
// terminology) to the router.
const ShowTheLocationWithRouter = withRouter(ShowTheLocation);
```

More information could be found [here](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/e634f0bad7796d128a4c4e2c4678487dd7256be2/packages/react-router/docs/api/withRouter.md).

Answer (score 15):

`withRouter` higher-order component allows you to get access to the `history` object’s properties and the closest `<Route>`'s match. `withRouter` will pass updated `match`, `location`, and `history` props to the wrapped component whenever it renders.

```js
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { withRouter } from "react-router";

// A simple component that shows the pathname of the current location
class ShowTheLocation extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    match: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    location: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    history: PropTypes.object.isRequired
  };

  render() {
    const { match, location, history } = this.props;

    return <div>You are now at {location.pathname}</div>;
  }
}

// Create a new component that is "connected" (to borrow redux
// terminology) to the router.
const ShowTheLocationWithRouter = withRouter(ShowTheLocation);
```

Comment: Read more about this here - https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/withRouter

Comment: is it the same with useRouteMatch/useHistory/useLocation when using function components?

Answer (score 3):

it is a higher order component which  will pass updated match, location, and history props to the wrapped component whenever it renders.
but I think it has been deprecated via react-router V6.in case of using its property you can use both `useLocation` or `useHistory` hooks.

here is a tiny higher order component which use these two hooks in order to implement behavior of `withRouter` :

```
export function withRouter(Children){
    return(props)=>{
       const location = useLocation();
       const history= useHistory();
       return <Children {...props} history= {history} location = {location}
               />
                    }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

withRouter is a higher-order component that will pass the closest route's to get access to some property as to location and match  from the props it can be accessed only if give the component the property located in the component

```
<Route to="/app" component={helo} history ={history} />
```

and same the match and location prosperity to be able to change the location and used this.props.history.push it should be provided for each component property must provide but when used WithRouter it can be access to location and match without add property history it can be accessed direction without add property history fro each Route.

Answer (score 0):

By default react router doesn't pass its all information to the component we are refering to

eg -
if we are having a route on a component Like below

```
 <Route path="/details/:id">
            <Details />
          </Route>
```

and we want to get some props from Route so for that we will have to use withRouter
To use it we will have to import it first by

```
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
```

and then use it while exporting the component

```
export default withRouter(Details);
```