# Why stream title is not rendering when whole stream object is returned from mapStateToProps?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm learning React from past two weeks.Currently I am taking course on Udemy of Stephen Grider.
I am building a dummy streaming platform just like twitch where I can create,delete,edit and watch streams.

Right now I was writing the **StreamDelete** component which will show a modal where the user can either delete the particular stream or cancel.

Here is the code what I have written:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

import React from "react";
import Modal from "../modal";
import history from "../../history";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { fetchIndividualStream } from "../../actions";

class streamDelete extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchIndividualStream(this.props.match.params.id);
  }

  action = () => {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <button className="ui button negative">Delete</button>
        <button className="ui button">Cancel</button>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  };

  renderContent = () => {
    return `Are you sure you want to delete : ${
      this.props.streams
        ? this.props.streams[this.props.match.params.id].title
        : ""
    }`;
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Modal
        title="Delete Stream"
        content={this.renderContent()}
        action={this.action()}
        onDismiss={() => history.push("/")}
      />
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return { stream: state.streams };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
  fetchIndividualStream,
})(streamDelete);
```

Here **fetchIndividualStream** action will fetch the stream which is to be deleted from the API and store it in the state.
The redux store after this operation looks like this
[image: state]

**Output I'm getting:**
[image: Output I'm getting]

**What should be the OUPUT:**
[image: This should be the output]
The modal will be present when the component first render with state as null as well as when the stream is successfully fetched.The only difference is after successful fetching the title will be displayed after "Are you sure you want to delete : ".See the `renderContent` method.

My problem is the modal is not displaying the title even after the state is updated just like the first image. I don't know the problem however on changing some code it worked.

The changes I made were in mapStateToProps and in the renderContent method.

**mapStateToProps**

```html
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
   return { stream: state.streams[ownProps.match.params.id] };
 };
```

**renderContent** method:

```html
renderContent = () => {
    return `Are you sure you want to delete : ${
       this.props.stream ? this.props.stream.title : ""
     }`;
   };
```

**EDIT**: [Link to the Github repository](https://github.com/yogesh021/streamy)

Comment: you need `withRouter` imported from react-router-dom

Answer (score 0):

You're seems to be using `react-router-dom` and want to get parameter from the url?

You need to use `withRoute` HOC to get access to `.match` / `this.props.match.params.id`. Please refer to example below.

Docs: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/withRouter
    connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(withRouter(Dashboard))

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { withRouter } from "react-router";

// A simple component that shows the pathname of the current location
class ShowTheLocation extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    match: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    location: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    history: PropTypes.object.isRequired
  };

  render() {
    const { match, location, history } = this.props;

    return <div>You are now at {location.pathname}</div>;
  }
}

// Create a new component that is "connected" (to borrow redux
// terminology) to the router.
const ShowTheLocationWithRouter = withRouter(ShowTheLocation);
```

So in your particular case you need to do this.

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
  fetchIndividualStream,
})(withRouter(streamDelete)); // withRouter higher order component.
```

Comment: why I cannot directly access the this.props.match.params.id from the component. Also why my later modification worked ?

Comment: What later modification?

Comment: In the mapStateToProps function and renderContent method. I mentioned this in my question.

Comment: it's hard for me to say without looking at the whole application. if you like you can put this on codesandbox.io so could take a deeper look. From code you've given you have this `this.props.stream.title` this is not the same as `this.props.streams[this.props.match.params.id].title`. You might be setting `streams.title` somewhere through some actions? but that's not coming from route params.

Comment: `this.props` refers to properties that are passed from parent. e.g. `<streamDelete match={}>` I am sure you're not setting that in parent. You're not just going to get access to a property that's not passed down. `withRouter` higher order component sets that property. [more on this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53539314/what-is-withrouter-for-in-react-router-dom)