# Invariant Violation: You should not use withRouter() outside a <Router> (with minimal working example)

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, router

Why do I get this error?

> Invariant Violation: You should not use withRouter() outside a <Router>

... and how do I fix it?

I think I am misuing withRouter somehow

```
import React, {Component} from "react"
import axios from "axios"
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'

class LoginForm extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    }

handleSubmit = (event) => {
    this.props.history.push("/dashboard")
}

render() {  
    return (
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>

                <input type="submit" />
            </form>
    )
}

}

export default withRouter( LoginForm )
```

index.js is just:

```
ReactDOM.render(
        <LoginForm />,
        document.getElementById("root")
)
```

Answer (score 1):

`withRouter` is a higher order component that will pass closest route's `match`, current `location`, and `history` props to the wrapped component whenever it renders. simply it connects component to the router. [source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56622289/11106685)

So your problem is that `withRouter` isn't able to connect to the **closest router** since there are none. You can fix it by adding one:

```
ReactDOM.render(
        <BrowserRouter>
            <LoginForm />
        </BrowserRouter>,
        document.getElementById("root")
)
```