# passing data between components via Link

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron

I'm working with my first electron app. I have a component that links to another component in another route.

I'm just not sure how to do it.

Here's my code:

```
<Link to={`${routes.SOMEPATH}?id=${id}`}>
  My Link
</Link>
```

When the user clicks the link, the new component is loaded, but how do I get the value for id?

Answer (score 0):

`id` should be stored in `this.props.match.params`.

[Passing props through React-Router v4 <Link />](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45598854/passing-props-through-react-router-v4-link)