# Navigate to anther component while on-form submit and passing the data to navigating component react Js

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I am new to this.I am sorry if maybe this question are already in  stack-overflow I cannot find-out perfect on  answer for my question

From fist component i get a input set to state. Now i need to pass the value to second component and navigate to second component while on-click from the fist component.
i already have navigation link. But **I need to navigate while  on-form submit and passing the data to navigating component**

*Note*

The fist component and second component are **Not Parent child component**.
These  two component are **individual independent component**.

Kindly help to  solve this

app.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import './App.css';
import Home from './components/Home';
import About from './components/About';
import Fist from './components/fist';
import Second from './components/Second';
import Navigation from './components/Navigation';
import Signup from './components/Signup';
import Signin from './components/Singin';

function App() {
return (
    <div className="App">
        <BrowserRouter>
            <div>

                <Navigation />
                <Switch>
                    <Route path="/" component={Home} exact />
                    <Route path="/Signin" component={Signin} />
                    <Route path="/Signup" component={Signup} />
                    <Route path="/fist" component={Fist} />
                    <Route path="/contact" component={Contact} />
                    <Route path="/Second" component={second} />


                </Switch>
            </div>
        </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
);
}

export default App;
```

Fist Class Component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Fist extends Component {

constructor(props) { super(props) ;}

  render() {
    return (
             <div>
            <input name="City" Placeholder="City" type="text" onChange={e => this.setState({ City: e.target.value }) }>
             <button class="loginbtn" type="submit" >Next </button>
           </div>
           );
           }
}
export default Fist;
```

Second Class component

```
 import React, { Component } from 'react';

 class Second extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        city: this.props.match.params
    } 
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <p> Code above </p>
            <p> {this.state.City}</p>
            <p> code below</p>
        </div>
    )
}
}
  export default Second;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass parameters on query like;

```
<Route path="/Second:city" component={second} />
```

And click from first link can be something like this;

```
<Link to={`/second/${this.state.city}`}>
```

Finally in second component you can get the city value with;

```
const { city } = this.props.match.params;
```

For more info: [Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45598854/passing-values-through-react-router-v4-link)

Comment: thank you so much  answer for me.  <Route path="/Second:city" component={second} /> this code change my url **http://localhost:3000/second/sending**  but the page not is played.  I'm missing any thing in second page constructor ? please help me

Comment: I'm update my second class component  in question . and need to navigate second component as programmatic  while on-click button.

Comment: Your url should be like localhost:3000/second/sending:berlin Then you can read it with this.props.match.params.city. So you should update your Link as I mentioned above in the answer.

Comment: Thanking you resolved  and so sorry for later.     In fist.js  `onclick (){    var str = "/Second/" + document.getElementById("city").value ;
        history.push(str);    } ` and second.js  ;
`this.setState({city : this.props.match.params.cityid })` are working  Finally resolve by  `import histroy.js`     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42672842/how-to-get-history-on-react-router-v4     Still  not get answer how to use history.js  in <BrowserRouter/>